# Play the video on Table Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I used custom `cell` to Play video in the cell. But all it does is that it show me the empty `tableView` `cell`, can somebody help me out?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let Custome = CustomeNavigation(nibName: "CustomeNavigation", bundle: nil)

    self.view.addSubview(Custome.view)
    Custome.lbl_customeTitle.text = "FEED"

    tableView.frame         =   CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:view.bounds.width, height:view.bounds.height);
    tableView.delegate      =   self
    tableView.dataSource    =   self

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    self.view.addSubview(tableView)

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
        {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VedioCell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

     let videoURL = NSURL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
     let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)

     let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
     playerLayer.frame = cell.bounds

     cell.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
     player.play()

     return cell
 }
```

Comment: Can you show the FeedCell class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to import `import AVKit` and `import AVFoundation`.

And you can try like this inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
let cell: FeedCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("VedioCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedCell

let videoURL = NSURL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
let player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL!)

let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = cell.bounds

cell.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
cell?.playerView?.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()

return cell
```

If you are using swift3 then the syntax is like this:

```
let videoURL = NSURL(string: "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4")
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)

let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = (cell?.bounds)!

cell?.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
cell?.playerView?.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()
```

And you also got to make sure you deal with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` if you are showing many of those.

Comment: Thank u .mr. Tarvo

Comment: if i want to play the Video when click the button inside of the cell how can i do that

Comment: Did it worked? Just use:

 `@IBAction func newPostButtonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
player.play()
}`

Comment: i had the custom cell inside the cell i placed the button when click the button play the video and stop video how can i do that ...please help me solve the issues

Comment: play the video inside the container cell